# GoJS resize every element of diagram

Tags: javascript, gojs

My diagram has elements of fixed size. For example I have couple elements with different sizes: First is 250x200px, second 307x501px etc.

There are lot of panels, shapes etc.

Is there any way to resize/rescale every element on current diagram?

For example I want to double every element size so I would like just multiply it by 2.

```
diagram.scale = diagram.scale * 2; //resize elements like 250px X 200px to 500px X 400px
```

I've read about scale and resizing from documentation but scale does not seem work.

I am not attaching any code because it is generic question.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that would work (to double the Diagram's scale) but that isn't exactly resizing elements.

You can programatically go over all nodes:

```
myDiagram.startTransaction();
myDiagram.nodes.each(function(node) {
  node.scale = node.scale * 2;
});
myDiagram.commitTransaction();
```

Or else resize them by setting their `width` and `height`, or setting the `width` and `height` of some element inside the node.

Maybe related depending on what you are trying to do: This tool extension demonstrates how to modify the ResizingTool to work with multiple selection: https://gojs.net/latest/extensions/ResizeMultiple.html